# How to create custom field in Shopware 6 and show it on frontend?

Tags: twig, frontend, shopware, storefront, shopware6

How do i make a custom created field in Shopware 6 and show it on the frontend/storefront by using a ***Twig*** file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings > System > Custom Fields -> Add new set. Or Add field to existing Custom field set.

Add this to the Twig template:

```
{{context.salesChannel.customFields.your_custom_field | trans}}
```

Change SalesChannel to the type the custom field is associated with.

Change **your_custom_field** to the  “technical name” specified in the custom field. “trans” is added to get the local translation.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the official [docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/custom-fields).